# Why are there empty circles next to these voice memos in itunes?

Tags: itunes, ipad, audio, mp3

I am having a problem finding voice recordings in my iPad. I already had this problem on my phone and none of the blogs nor threads on Apple's site have worked.

I upgraded to iTunes 12.1.2.27

On my iPhone I already did a sync with voice memos. Ever since I put to import audio files as mp3 there is nothing showing up. Just these empty circles

[image]

So i used the voice recorder app on my iPad and now in my iTunes I don't see anything that I can even play. Nor do I even know what those circles are.

Comment: The empty circle means the file should be in the process of syncing, or is supposed to have synced but did not for some reason.

Comment: I tried syncing it at least 5 times. I even got a message that it went through fine. Yet I see these. I updated iTunes to make sure it was not an old bug, but sill having this issue.